# How do I negate a condition in PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell

How do I negate a conditional test in PowerShell?

For example, if I want to check for the directory C:\Code, I can run:

```
if (Test-Path C:\Code){
  write "it exists!"
}
```

Is there a way to negate that condition, e.g. (non-working):

```
if (Not (Test-Path C:\Code)){
  write "it doesn't exist!"
}
```

---

**Workaround**:

```
if (Test-Path C:\Code){
}
else {
  write "it doesn't exist"
}
```

This works fine, but I'd prefer something inline.

Answer (score 677, accepted):

You almost had it with `Not`. It should be:

```
if (-Not (Test-Path C:\Code)) {
    write "it doesn't exist!"
}
```

You can also use `!`: `if (!(Test-Path C:\Code)){}`

Just for fun, you could also use bitwise exclusive or, though it's not the most readable/understandable method.

```
if ((test-path C:\code) -bxor 1) {write "it doesn't exist!"}
```

Comment: Interesting, so `-not` comes with the traditional alternative of `!` then? Can I somehow get the traditional alternatives for `-eq` and `-ne` too?

Comment: No, `-not` is the only logical operator that comes with an alternate (see `help about_Logical_Operators`), and operators cannot be aliased.

Comment: Thanks, I was missing fact that the use of `!` required parentheses.

Comment: _The term '!Test-Path' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet ..._ :)

Comment: I wish there were a better way that supported piping. E.g. `Get-ChildItem -r -inc *.txt | !Test-Path`

Comment: "Just for fun" - it's all fun until we come back to our code 6 months later.

Answer (score 14):

Powershell also accept the C/C++/C* not operator

```
 if ( !(Test-Path C:\Code) ){ write "it doesn't exist!" }
```

I use it often because I'm used to C*...
allows code compression/simplification...
I also find it more elegant...

Answer (score 11):

If you are like me and dislike the double parenthesis, you can use a function

```sh
function not ($cm, $pm) {
  if (& $cm $pm) {0} else {1}
}

if (not Test-Path C:\Code) {'it does not exist!'}
```

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/velour/blob/943be2d/install.ps1#L2-L4)

Comment: I like this, but probably can't use this `not` implementation everywhere (for example `not Test-Path -path C:\Code` won't work). See also this related [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31888580/450913).

Comment: Perl has a more logical, in the Vulcan sense, idiom, called Unless, which is written as a function. Being half Vulcan, I prefer it, and have implemented it in both C#, as a function, and in C and C++, as a macro.

Comment: @DavidA.Gray Ruby has `unless` as keyword (just like `if`) but most user from other languages hate it.

Answer (score 6):

if you don't like the double brackets or you don't want to write a function, you can just use a variable.

```
$path = Test-Path C:\Code
if (!$path) {
    write "it doesn't exist!"
}
```